# my list view in side the splitview is not scrolling

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, windows-10-universal

my list view inside the split view is not scrolling.

XAML code of total page goes like below.

```
<SplitView ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled="True" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" x:Name="windowssplit1" DisplayMode="Overlay" Margin="40,-95,0,-200" Width="340" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:FieldModifier="Public" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <SplitView.Pane>
            <!--<Grid Background="Gray" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="True">-->
                <StackPanel Background="Gray" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="True" Margin="0,49,0,-162">
                <TextBlock Text="All Ages" Margin="20,10,0,10" Foreground="White" FontSize="20" />
                <Border BorderThickness="0.4" BorderBrush="White" Margin="20,0,0,10" Width="280" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <ListView x:Name="filterlist1" Margin="10,0,0,0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled="True" SelectionChanged="filterlist_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="18" Margin="0,10,0,0" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding CategoryName}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            <!--</Grid>-->
            </StackPanel>
        </SplitView.Pane>
    </SplitView>
```

The List View present in the Bolded Code must Scroll how this can be done, Help me....
How to make the List scroll 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to put your listview inside a scrolViwer !

Comment: ListViews have a built in ScrollViewer by default.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has to do with the panel that the `ListView` is in. Set the ListView to have a 'fixed' `MaxHeight` so that it can know when to scroll.

```
    <ListView x:Name="filterlist1" Margin="10,0,0,0" 
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" 
        ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled="True" 
        SelectionChanged="filterlist_SelectionChanged"
        MaxHeight="400">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18" Margin="0,10,0,0" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding CategoryName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Okay, must be a WPF specific property then. ill update. Did setting the MaxWidth work?

Answer (score 0):

To make the `ListView` scrollable, we need give the `ListView` a explicit height or use a layout that can limit the height of `ListView`.

`StackPanel` is not suitable for this scenario as it won't limit the size of `ListView`. All items are showed in the `ListView`, but only these items in `StackPanel` can be seen.

We can use `Grid` instead of `StackPanel` and try with following code:

```
<SplitView x:Name="windowssplit1"
           Grid.RowSpan="2"
           Width="340"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           BorderBrush="White"
           BorderThickness="1"
           DisplayMode="Overlay"
           IsPaneOpen="True"
           x:FieldModifier="Public">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <Grid Background="Gray">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Margin="20,10,0,10"
                       FontSize="20"
                       Foreground="White"
                       Text="All Ages" />
            <Border Width="280"
                    Margin="20,0,0,10"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    BorderBrush="White"
                    BorderThickness="0.4" />
            <ListView x:Name="filterlist1"
                      Grid.Row="1"
                      Margin="10,0,0,0"
                      SelectionChanged="filterlist_SelectionChanged">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0"
                                   FontSize="18"
                                   Foreground="White"
                                   Text="{Binding CategoryName}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </SplitView.Pane>
</SplitView>
```

Here I set two rows in `Grid` and put the `ListView` in the second row. Second row's `Height` is set to `*` so it can get the rest Height of the `Grid`. I also remove the `Margin` in `SplitView` to see the scroll bar clearly.